# Google Play Private Channel - Releasing to specific external users

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps

I've got my personal Google Play Developer account, but within the company I work for, I'd like to start distributing an app. We have a Google Apps account with a very limited number of users - (we only have 5 people on the account), while the company itself has a few thousand employees.

Ultimately, we'd want to distribute to a wider array of people (people who are not on the Google Apps account) and potentially even include users who are not employees.

I imagine setting up a "white-list" of external users who can see the app, download it, get updates - but I can't find out whether this exists or not for private channels. Before I request the company pay the $25 for a developer account so that I can see whether or not this is possible, I was wondering if anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can I publish an app to a specific group of users?

No. But you can publish an app targeting a specific country or specific device models."

"Can I publish an app to both the public Google Play store and a Private Channel?

This functionality is not supported in the initial release. An app can either be published publicly or to a Private Channel, and not both."

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

Comment: I don't want it to be on the public store - just the private channel. I just want to be able to select which users outside our organization would be able to see it.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstand but to reach users outside your channel I believe you would have to publish to the play store even if you only allowed a specific community to download from there via the alpha beta restricted releases

Comment: That's what I figure. That's too bad.